# How to pass value of a variable in ssh command

Tags: command-line, ssh

If i made a test.sh in local system with the content.

```
!/bin/bash
cd /Documents/test/sandbox 
LatLong=java -jar test2.jar cape_town
ssh root@target 'cd /some path && ./DriveSimulator $LatLong'
```

How do i get the value of **LatLong** to be passed in the ssh command? Because the above method now gives a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**LatLong** is defined in the local system/session but you are trying to use it on the remote as if it was defined there. Try replacing the single quote with double. Also I suggest to put the variable assignment in quotes

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /Documents/test/sandbox 
LatLong=$(java -jar test2.jar cape_town)
echo here is LatLong $LatLong
ssh root@target "cd /some path && ./DriveSimulator $LatLong"
```

This way the variable **LatLong** will be interpolated before sending it to the remote host